# How to click a link by using Selinium 2

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I want to click the flip kart new user login page, by clicking the login link, but I am not able to do so.

```
public WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    public void reg(){
        driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/");
        /*driver.manage().window();*/
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='container']/div/header/div[1]/div[1]/div/ul/li[9]/a")).click();

    }
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

You should try using `WebDriverWait` with `By.linkText()` locator to click on `login` link as below :-

```
driver.get("http://www.flipkart.com/");

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Log In"))).click();
```

Comment: still i am not able to click the link ...can any one help me

Comment: What do you mean not able?? Is there any exception??